# Creating a modal dialog

Tags: qt, qml

I created an empty Qt Quick Application, created a dialog and set the modal to "true", but it's not modal and the dialog disappears when the user clicks outside the dialog

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: pickList.open()

    Dialog{
        id: pickList
        modal: true
        width: 400
        height: 400

    }
}
```

Comment: You should set appropriate [closePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#closePolicy-prop). Default value is ` Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutside` so clicking outside closes it.

Comment: That DOES solve the problem, thanks